# reading .mxd file without using arcMap software or any others ones

Tags: javascript, python, django, arcgis, shapefile

I have many `.mxd` files that needed to convert to `shape File` (.shp) or `JsonObject` I want to find a way to do this by code `js or python code or API` Not by using the Arc Map software manually. Is there any way?
I am using vanilla js for the frontend and Django for the backend
I mean can we read `.mxd files` or convert them to a file that we can read ?  without using `ArcMap` or `QGIS`

Is `arcpy` my solution ?

Comment: Do you mean no software at all?

Comment: yes ,no software at all , just  with only code (js or python)

Comment: [Introduction to arcpy.mapping - ArcMap | Documentation](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-mapping/introduction-to-arcpy-mapping.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Mxd's reference datasources the file itself does not contain any data. So you have to loop through the mxd layers and find the sources and export those (if appropriate). As far as I am aware mxd's can only be read by arcgis/esri software, and yes arcpy is the correct tool to use but you'll only be able to utilise arcpy if you have arcmap/arcgis pro installed and licenced.

Check out arcpy documentation and examples;
listlayers for layers in the mxd https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-mapping/listlayers.htm, layer for the datasource https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-mapping/layer.htm
and lastly feature class to feature class to export the layers to shapefile
https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/conversion-toolbox/feature-class-to-feature-class.htm or to geojson using https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/conversion-toolbox/features-to-json.htm